# AS3 Packaging external files into one stand-alone.swf

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, adobe, embed, package

I've created a very large scale Flash game and have apparently had a massive oversight - the flash portal websites wishing to host my game need it in one stand alone .swf. However, the problem is I load **everything** externally. I load the level data from .plist files, the images from .png and the sound from .wav, all located in folders in the .swf directory. They're loaded through Loader's and URLRequest.

Is there any way I can embed these so it will run as a stand alone? Preferably an easier way than individually writing embed lines, as there are 1000s of files.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: Because you use Loaders and URLRequests, every asset needs to be accessed as an external request. You ask for a simple way to have them point to assets inside your SWF, which is not possible. However, if you change your workflow a bit, you might find a way that is acceptible in terms of code changes, and will benefit you in the long run.

If you use an editor like Flash Builder, FDT, FlashDevelop or IntelliJ, you should explore the many uses of SWC files. You can hit the 'export as SWC' checkmark in the Flash IDE's publish settings, which will create a SWC every time you test (Cmd+Enter) the fla file. You can import that SWC file in your editor of choice, and reference any symbols of your original fla file as AS3 classes. On compile, the flash compiler will take your original assets and embed them into the resulting SWF, that you can then distribute to any portal website you like. PNGs and WAVs are the easiest, for .plist you'll have to use the `[Embed(...)]` meta tag. Benefits next to having one SWF are also that you don't need to preload each separate asset and that all asset creation is done in one thread. No more event listener spaghetti for loading assets!

Make sure you name your symbols and linkage properties appropriately for using SWCs. You can use the standard package format to easily find your assets, like naming a symbol `fla.icons.GreyLogo` or `fla.homepage.BackgroundGraphic`. If you then have the correct `import fla.icons.GreyLogo` direction in place, you can get at the logo by calling

```
var logo:GreyLogo = new GreyLogo();
```

[Here is an article that goes into this a little more thorougly.](http://www.beautifycode.com/how-to-use-swc-assets-in-fdt) It will be a lot of work if I understand your setup correctly, but it might turn out to be advantageous in future projects.

Cheers,
EP.